# могу ли я задать тип, значение переменной и условие внутри condition условного оператора if?

Tags: c++

как пример:

```
if (condition) {
//
}
```

где condition включает в себя вышеперечисленные параметры? (тип, значение переменной и условие внутри)?

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так? Будет работать начиная с C++17. Вот [тут](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/if-else-statement-cpp?view=msvc-170) больше об этом.

```cpp
if (int i = 11; i > 10) {
    cout << i; // 11
}
```

---

То что вы попросили дополнительно. Строк может и меньше стало, а как это читать теперь? Ну ладно, дело ваше.

```cpp
if (int i = 0; cin >> i && i > 10) {
    cout << i;
}
```

Comment: да, нечто похожее, но, получить значение переменной, через ввод

Comment: ввод внутри `if(...)`?

Comment: да! именно так!

Comment: @scoobydaq, какая от этого практическая польза? Почему бы не получить ввод до условия?

Comment: сократить количество строк?

Comment: @scoobydaq и в тоже время читаемость. Я обновил ответ.

Comment: @scoobydaq, в с++ переносы строк не важны - всю программу можно записать в одну строку